# how can I make "scroll-to-fullscreen" with UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

everyone. I'm a super beginner of ios app programming, and am totally in trouble to make views with TabBar which will be hidden with scrolling up/down on scrollviews.
(Views would be pinterest-like...)

I thoroughly searched on web, and found a library like this;
[YIFullScreenScroll from GitHub](https://github.com/inamiy/YIFullScreenScroll)

However, in this sample, it seems TabBar and ToolBar appear and disappear only on the top of the view, and were not working in the middle of the screen.

I really would like to know how to control TabBar and ToolBar's hidden even in the middle of the scroll view.(Like Pinterest...)

Apologies for my messy writings in advance...

But,Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Pinterest so I hope I understood correctly what you are trying to do.
I am kinda new to objective-c myself, so perhaps there is a much simpler way to do it, but this gets the job done.

I am not a native english speaker, so if my explanation isn't clear enough, tell me, and I'll try to rephrase it.

First, conform to UIScrollView delegate and create 2 properties to hold the original frame of the tab bar and navigation bar

Also, set your scroll view's delegate to be your view controller, either from interface builder or by code

```
ViewController.m  
@interface ViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>  
@property (nonatomic) CGRect navBarFrame;  
@property (nonatomic) CGRect tabBarFrame;  
@end
```

Then, in viewDidLoad, set the above properties

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
    [super viewDidLoad]  
    self.navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;  
    self.tabBarFrame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;  
}
```

Now we will use the scroll view's delegate method to determine when a scroll has began.

First we begin with the delegate that gets called when a scroll begins, to hide the navigation and tab bars

```
- (void)scrollViewDidBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  
{  
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3
                      delay: 0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations: ^(void){
                     CGFloat tabBarX = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x;
                     CGFloat tabBarWidth = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width;
                     CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
                     self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(tabBarX, self.view.frame.size.height, tabBarWidth, tabBarHeight);

                     CGFloat navBarX = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.x;
                     CGFloat navBarWidth = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width;
                     CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
                     self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(navBarX, 0, navBarWidth, navBarHeight);
                 }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                     if(finished){
                         [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden: YES];
                         [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden: YES];
                     }
                 }];
}
```

Now we will use 2 delegate methods to determine when a scroll ends to to show the tab bar and navigation bar again.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate  
{  
if(!decelerate){

    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden: NO];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden: NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3
                     animations: ^(void){
                         self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = self.tabBarFrame;
                         self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = self.navBarFrame;
                     }];
        }
}  


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  
{  
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden: NO];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden: NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3
                     animations: ^(void){
                         self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = self.tabBarFrame;
                         self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = self.navBarFrame;
                 }];
}
```

The reason we are calling 2 separate methods is that the first one is getting called whenever a user stops scrolling, even if the scroll view is still scrolling (like when you scroll really fast, and then you stop scrolling, the scroll view is still scrolling for a couple of seconds, until it stops entirely)
The first method also have a variable, 'decelerate', which checks to see if the scroll is still scrolling.
Since I didn't want to show the tab bar and navigation bar while the scroll view is still scrolling,
The first method will run the code the show the navigation and tab bars again, only if 'decelerate' is false, meaning the scroll is stopped,

The second method only gets called if the scroll view did scroll after the user stopped scrolling, and only when the scroll ends.
And then we will run the same code as above, to show the tab and navigation bars again.

What we are basically doing is just creating an animation, which moves the frame of the tab and navigation bars out of the view or into the view.

I randomly set the animation duration to be 0.3,
You can change it to be more or less if you want the bars to be shown and hidden faster or slower.

Good luck mate.

Comment: Thank you so much for your source! your explanation is clear enough so I did not need further rephrasing....I examined the methods you gave me, and I found it working! However,with '- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate' method, the animation looked odd a little. So as you suggest, I will use another method. Anyway, thank you so much for your help!!!!